# Blogger API Gives Error 500 when Requesting List of Scheduled Posts

Tags: api, google-api, blogger, internal-server-error

I am using Blogger API v3. When requesting a list of scheduled status posts, the API always returns error 500. First I thought it might just be my blog or my app. However, I've tested on the API's own website (try it out) on a newly created blog and it still happens. Does anyone else have this same problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Of course, this is assuming you already have scheduled posts in your blog though.

Comment: I tried using the Try This API section ( present in https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list ) on a blog with scheduled posts and it returned a 200 response.

Answer (score 1):

> The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that
>   means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server
>   could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

Reference : https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/display/WES/What+Is+A+500+error

Q : Does anyone else have this same problem?

A : Yes, I have, several times.

In fact, the 500 error is not only happen when we request a list of posts but also in every request we can make with Blogger API. AFAIK, when I do a request with Blogger API and it's returned 500 error, it's always because when doing multiple request in almost the same time (usually because of looping which I forgot to break)

I've also encounter this error when testing it straight from the Blogger API examples page. The first time I request it retured 500 error, but the second time, the request the returned the data that I requested.

For the sample in Blogger API site, it may be just an authentication error. As for the error by your own request, I suggest you to check your coding again, the  the request may be placed inside a looping or you've send a request **BEFORE** the previous request has successfully returned a response.